# Webapp freezees when using component in some scenarios

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I`m building an web app in Angular. 
I have a parent component and a list of child components. The data is sent by an rxjs Subject. 
The child component is used in another part of the app where it works, although not in an `*ngFor` structure

The webapp freezes even when i have only one element in the "entries" array.
I tried only initializing the component, without sending any "messages", but it still freezes

There is a infinite loop in calling a getter ( validEntries).

This component is used else where and there it works as expected.
parent.component.html

```
<div class="option" *ngFor="let entry of entries">
   <app-options-previewer [events]="optionsChanged" [index]="0"></app-options-previewer>
</div>
```

child.component.html

```
<mat-chip color="primary" selected *ngFor="let entry of validEntries">{{entry.name}}</mat-chip>
    <mat-chip color="primary" *ngIf="validEntries.length==0">No option selected</mat-chip>
```

the faultry getter:

```
 get validEntries(): Array<CommandEntryOption> {
    console.log("valid entries get");
    if (this.entries !== undefined)
      return this.entries.filter(function (value) { return value.quantity > 0 });
    else
      return [];
  }
```

Actual result: App freezes
Expected result: There should be a child component for every entry in the array entries.

If there is any more info i should provide, please mention it.

Comment: Hard to understand your code. Never used Subject in that way. I dont think its possible to call a Subject as Array. Its an Observable. Your subject is of Type `<OptionMessage>` so its watching ONE message at a time. Now you are trying to call this Subject as an Array and want to push on this not existing array the Values. I get the idea. But it should be like `Subject<OptionMessage[]>` and there u do: `this.optionsChanged.next([OptionMessageA,OptionMessageB...]`

Comment: sorry, wrong code :) updating the answer now

Comment: Also, even with that part comented, as in i am not sending anything through the subject, the app still freezes.

Comment: Don't you get any console error ?

Comment: No errors in console.

Comment: Could you please provide your Classes `OptionMessage` and `CommandEntryOption` in a short overview.

Comment: Adding to the question now

Comment: Updated the question with what I found by placing some console.logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was binding ngfor on a getter. I replaced it by a property which just stores a the value of the getter. I asign the value on ngOnInit(), and every time I need it to be changed;